# NOVA [Errno 111] Connection refused

Tags: python, cloud, openstack

I am trying to deploy icehouse version of openstack.
I am running `nova image-list` and in response error is coming which is `ERROR: [Errno 111] Connection refused`.

I am not able to get any kind of logs due to which i am unable to find anything concrete to go further but i am able to get few things.

1) When i run `nova --debug image-list` i get http://pastebin.com/zSBuADKb.

2) netstat -tpln is giving me this

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      29774/python 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9292            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      5179/python 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:35357           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      29774/python 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8775            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9375/python     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9191            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      5130/python
```

My endpoint is stating to use port 8774 but here port 8775 is used which i am not able to understand.

3) nova-manage service list is giving

```
Binary           Host                                 Zone             Status     State Updated_At
nova-cert        ShivamS                              internal         enabled    :-)   2015-04-07 15:45:27
nova-consoleauth ShivamS                              internal         enabled    :-)   2015-04-07 15:45:27
nova-scheduler   ShivamS                              internal         enabled    :-)   2015-04-07 15:45:28
nova-conductor   ShivamS                              internal         enabled    :-)   2015-04-07 15:45:28
nova-console     ShivamS                              internal         enabled    :-)   2015-04-07 15:45:28
nova-compute     ShivamS                              nova             enabled    :-)   2015-04-07 15:45:28
```

4) When i am doing curl to endpoint of keystone or glance then i am getting response but in case of nova i am getting `curl: (7) couldn't connect to host`

From all this i am thinking that endpoint is not getting made correctly but i am not able to get any thing from logs so i have no clue how to get this right. All logs contain is related to connection to AMQP server.

Please help as i am not able to think at all what to do on this and i have seen previous question related to same error but they are of no help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after banging my head i finally found the answer and it was my error due to not enabling `osapi_compute` api in nova.conf.